# Try...catch mysteriously continues executing code (only sometimes...)

Tags: c#, multithreading, try-catch

In the C# code below, assume that `sample` is, say, 20000. 
Then the line which calls `Convert.ToInt16` will throw an overflow exception as it tries to convert 20000 * 3.2 (which is greater than 32768).

In that exception, it sets a bool flag to true (dataErrorWritten), which is supposed to stop the error message being written more than once.

However what I am seeing is some cases where the error message is continually written every time and it appears the `dataErrorWritten` flag is not doing anything. How can this be possible? Once the exception is caught the first time, `dataErrorWritten[i]` will be set to true, and when it comes around the next time it should not print any error. In fact, this works 99% of the time, however under certain strange circumstances it does not.

ProcessInData is running on its own thread within a static class.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. 
I have already tracked down one multi-threading bug in this program (shared data queue without lock), and I guess that this might have something to do with multi-threading but I can't see how.

```
private static bool[] dataErrorWritten;

private static void ProcessInData()
{

    short[][] bufferedData = new short[800][];
    short sample;


    //initialise this bool array to false 
    dataErrorWriten = new bool[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        dataErrorWriten[i] = false; 
    }

    //create buffered data arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferedData.Length; i++)
    {
        bufferedData[i] = new short[32];
    }

    //loop always true
    while (processData)
    {
        //... Increment bufferLocation

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

            //Get a sample of data
            sample = GetSampleFromSomewhere(); 

            try {
                bufferedData[bufferLocation][i] = Convert.ToInt16(((float)sample * 3.2);
                dataErrorWritten[i] = false;
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                if (!dataErrorWritten[i]) {
                    EventLog.WriteToErrorLogFile("Invalid UDP sample value " + sample + " received for channel " + (i + 1).ToString() + ".");
                    dataErrorWritten[i] = true;
                }

                // ... set buffered data within bounds

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sets the flag to false after a successful convert and true in the handler.

If your code had a mix of good and bad converts, the flag will toggle and you get multiple errors.

You could remove the set back to "false" to ensure each error is only printed once. Perhaps use a counter instead of a bool. Only output the error when the counter is 0. That way you know how many times the error occurred (for debug purposes), but only report it once.